# parseFloat on regex parameter returning NaN

Tags: javascript, regex, parameters

I am trying to manipulate some float values inside of a string by a certain amount. To do so I have the following:

```js
var string = '<path d="M219.6,-71.4C249,19.1,212.7,130.9,135.7,186.8C58.8,242.7,-58.8,242.7,-135.7,186.8C-212.7,130.9,-249,19.1,-219.6,-71.4C-190.2,-161.8,-95.1,-230.9,0,-230.9C95.1,-230.9,190.2,-161.8,219.6,-71.4Z" />';
var regex = /[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+/g;
console.log(string.replace(regex, parseFloat("$&") + 300));
```

How come it is replacing the `parseFloat("$&")` with `NaN`? What's the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is equivalent to writing

```
var temp = parseFloat("$&") + 300;
document.body.innerText = string.replace(regex, temp);
```

because function arguments are evaluated *before* calling the function. `"$&"` only has special meaning if it's literally in the replacement string that `replace()` gets, it doesn't have any special meaning to `parseFloat()`, and it's not possible for `replace()` to reach into the `parseFloat()` call and modify the parameter.

If you want to call a function to determine the replacement, you need to pass a function reference to the `replace()` function, not an expression containing the function call.

```js
var string = '<path d="M219.6,-71.4C249,19.1,212.7,130.9,135.7,186.8C58.8,242.7,-58.8,242.7,-135.7,186.8C-212.7,130.9,-249,19.1,-219.6,-71.4C-190.2,-161.8,-95.1,-230.9,0,-230.9C95.1,-230.9,190.2,-161.8,219.6,-71.4Z" />';
var regex = /[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+/g;
var newString = string.replace(regex, match => parseFloat(match) + 300);
console.log(newString)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Apparently I missed the "`replacement` can be a string or a function to be called for each match" part of the documentation.

Comment: I settled on `match => Math.round((parseFloat(match) + 300.0001) * 100) / 100)` per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-only-if-necessary#comment28521418_11832950) to drop those pesky floating point errors.

Comment: If you want 2 decimal digits, use `toFixed(parseFloat(match)+300), 2)`. It will do the necessary rounding as well.

Comment: Right, but that adds digits to numbers that don't have any, which I don't want.

Answer (score 1):

See the parseFloat [definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)

> A floating point number parsed from the given value. If the value
>   cannot be converted to a number, NaN is returned.

So clearly you have a string there which can't be converted to a Number.

Comment: Right, but if I change the replace to "" it removes all of them, so it's matching them properly - the real question is what's the proper way to parse them. Not what happens if it can't be parsed using `parseFloat`.